# jQuery - if всегда возвращает true

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

Делаю карусель на jQuery и хочу задать следующие условие. Если отображается первый элемент карусели, то по нажатию на правую кнопку позиция будет сдвигаться вправо на ширину одного блока, а если последний, то при нажатии на эту же кнопку позиция будет сдвигать слева, возвращаясь к первому блоку. Таким образом хочу реализовать цикличность прокрутки.
Пробовал через `.position()`, там `if` всегда возвращало `true`. Решил создать переменную, которая будет содержать в себе информацию о том какой блок сейчас активен, но столкнулся с то же проблемой.
Вот код:

```
if ($ActiveElement === 1) {
    $carouselNextButton.on('click', function(){
        $carouselInner.animate({left: '-=2560px'}, 'fast');
        $ActiveElement = 2;
        console.log($ActiveElement);
    });
} else if ($ActiveElement === 2) {
    $carouselPrevButton.on('click', function(){
        $carouselInner.animate({left: '+=2560px'}, 'fast');
    });
}
```

Сначала первое условие выполняется как положено и в консоль выдается информация о том, что `$ActiveElement === 2`, но потом не срабатывает второе условия.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка?

Comment: если в консоль вывелась _информация о том, что $ActiveElement === 2_ - значит отработал обработчик клика, и к этому моменту это условие уже было давно пройдено

Comment: Почему после не проходит повторная проверка и не срабатывает иное условие?

Comment: Потому что **асинхронищина**.

Comment: а почему должно проходить это условие? был назначен обработчик, он и работает. и будет работать пока его не переназначат, в текущем коде, он **не** переназначается

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, по моему уже был вроде подобный вопрос с if и обработчиками, не помнишь?

Comment: @Grundy, на моей памяти были только с определением переменной во вне асинхронной функции (что мало отличается)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Дайте, пожалуйста, совет новичку. Хочется разобраться с возникшей проблемой и заполнить пробел в знаниях.

Comment: в каком месте у тебя этот if написан?

Comment: @cerberus Внутри функции, которая вызывается сразу после описания. И все это внутри $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: @andreyb1990 тогда у тебя обработчик второй не создается вообще, так ведь?)

Comment: @cerberus Получается, что так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

функция [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) только добавляет обработчик, который вызовется по клику, но не выполняет его. Таким образом само условие выполняется **один** раз устанавливая обработчик, и больше к нему управление не возвращается.

Для решения нужно логику перенести *внутрь* обработчика:

1. определить какой элемент показывается сейчас
2. в зависимости от этого прокрутить на один элемент, либо на все.